# SqlDataReader to Dictionary using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

We have SqlDataReader as source. Can we map it with Dictionary using Automapper having custom key.

Details are as below,

- SqlDataReader ==> dr(oMessage,oError) ==> dr contains this return items
- Dictionary  ==> Dictionary<"Message",value from dr oMessage>
- Dictionary  ==> Dictionary<"Error",value from dr oError>

Comment: Why do you want to use AutoMapper in this scenario? I don't think that a solution with AutoMapper is easier to read or maintain than a straightforward one.

Comment: Thanks for your review...but my Managr want it like that :)

Comment: @nawfal the type of Dictionay is <string,string>. The Key value will be Custom and declare at the time of creating.

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper was created to map from a type to another representation. Your scenario is not a classic mapping scenario as you want to extract values from a specific DataReader and store them in a Dictionary. If it was about mapping, you'd map more or less any SqlDataReader instance to a Dictionary, in an extreme regardless of which data a SqlDataReader instance accesses.
The big advantage of using AutoMapper is to reduce the amount of code that is needed for 80% of the mapping scenarios. It is a flexible framework, so you might be able to configure the Mapper so that it supports your scenario. But the amount of code that is needed to achieve this is at least the same amount that you'd need when you implement the transformation from the data in the SqlDataReader to a dictionary in a classic way without using AutoMapper. Plus, the classic approach would be much easier to read and understand as the transformation is not hidden behind a lot of AutoMapper configuration.
Therefore, I'd suggest to go with the classic approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible. I used AutoMapper to wrap the AX Business Connector, which behaves very similarly to the Data Reader- you can see the full implementation [here](https://github.com/tdietrich513/AxBcWrapper), including an IQueryable provider. If you strip out the IQueryable stuff and just concentrate on the ClassMapping, SessionFactory, and Session classes you could modify this code to push out a dictionary.

I would advise considering a MicroORM for this task, however.